# Whats wrong with this Jquery selector code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to focus the first valid element inside my form when the function is called, so I wrote this code:

```
function focusFirst(id) {
    $("#" + id + " input:visible:enabled:not([readonly]), #" + id + "textarea:visible:enabled:not([readonly]), #" + id + " select:visible:enabled:not([readonly])").first().focus();
}
```

and called it like this:

```
oncomplete="focusFirst('formCadastro')"
```

My form is named: "formCadastro", anyway it won't work, but when I change to this:

```
function focusFirstFormCadastro() {
    $("#formCadastro input:visible:enabled:not([readonly]), #formCadastro textarea:visible:enabled:not([readonly]), #formCadastro select:visible:enabled:not([readonly])").first().focus();
}
```

it works. So the question here is how to concatenate my id inside the selector?

Comment: Consider to use `.find()` for readability or even pass element (jq or not) instead of string ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For readability, you should use relevant transversal/filtering methods instead:

```
function focusFirst(id) {
    $("#" + id).find('input, textarea').filter(':visible:enabled:not([readonly])').first().focus();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a space after the second id:

```
function focusFirst(id) {
    $("#" + id + " input:visible:enabled:not([readonly]), #" + id + " textarea:visible:enabled:not([readonly]), #" + id + " select:visible:enabled:not([readonly])").first().focus();
}
```

Comment: Oh lol, you beat me :(

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add a space between ID en textarea: Update link like so:

```
$("#" + id + " input:visible:enabled:not([readonly]), #" + id + " textarea:visible:enabled:not([readonly]), #" + id + " select:visible:enabled:not([readonly])").first().focus();
```